# python 3.3 and beautifulsoup4-4.3.2

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.3

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import socket

searchurl = "http://suchen.mobile.de/auto/search.html?scopeId=C&isSearchRequest=true&sortOption.sortBy=price.consumerGrossEuro"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(searchurl, None, None)
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in soup.find_all("div","listEntry "):
            print(link)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taha\Documents\worksapcetoon\Parser\com\test__init__.py", line 6, in 
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(searchurl, None, None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For urllib.request docs look here:

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.request.urlopen

use `import urllib.request` instead of `import urllib`

Comment: i work with 3.3 and that's to different from using 3.0 i think and  my knowledge of python is 20% :p but i want to use it for parsing did you have any god tutorial :)

Comment: I haven't got any tutorials, you must use google for it. But if you wanna solve the problem in code which you shared, replace your `import urllib` with `import urllib.request`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
import urllib
```

with:

```
import urllib.request
```

Python by default doesn't include submodules into packages' namespace - it must be done by hand by programmer. Some packages are written to do it - for example package 'os' puts 'path' in own namespace so 'import os' is enough to use both 'os' and 'os.path' functions - but in general all module imports need to be explicit.